# How to load below link to spark-shell or pyspark

Tags: apache-spark

can I load this into the spark-shell/pyspark
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/master/data/retail-data/all/online-retail-dataset.csv

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
sparkSession.read.csv.option("header", true).csv(filePath)
```